# Google MAP API v3: Move center between two locs

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I move the camera from one loc to another loc ? I have checked the API but I couldn't find what I want beside the `setCenter` method which directly sets the center to the given location but I want to a smooth transtition, not an instant center change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

Method `panTo`.

> Changes the center of the map to the
>   given LatLng. If the change is less
>   than both the width and height of the
>   map, the transition will be smoothly
>   animated.